# Return a value from SQL query and display in android

Tags: android, sql

im looking working on an app where the user can read information through the app thats stored on the database. Using an sql query, i want to return the value and output this on the app so the user can read it when they click on the "View Notes" button.

SQL Query saved in PHP

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$id = $_POST['UserID'];

$query_search = "select MedicalNotes from PatientRecords where PatientID = 1";

$result = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


?>
```

I then want to run this query through the app when the user clicks the "View Notes" button.

Do i use the,

```
    httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://database.location.ac.uk/app/queries/notes.php");
```

?

Comment: why you dont use native android sqllite? (rawquery/execsql)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this ([link](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/2/)).

A little example that might work:

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("myDatabase.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

String select = "select MedicalNotes from PatientRecords where PatientID = 1";
Cursor dbCursor = myDB.rawQuery(select, null);

dbCursor.moveToFirst();
while (dbCursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
{
    // Do stuff here with Cursor's getXXX method
    // ex. String data = dbCursor.getString(0);
    dbCursor.moveToNext();
}
dbCursor.close();
```